# Python ABC seems to allow incomplete implementation

Tags: python, abstract-class, abc

I'm trying to create base class and force all subclasses to implement it's interface. I'm using the `abc` module for this purpose.

Here is the base class:

```
class PluginBase:
    __metaclass = abc.ABCMeta
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def strrep(self):
            return
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def idle(self):
            print 'PluginBase: doing nothing here'
            pass
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def say(self, word):
            print 'PluginBase: saying a word ''', word, '\''
            return
```

And here is the child:

```
class ConcretePlugin(PluginBase):
    def __init__(self, val):
            print 'initialising ConcretePlugin with value of %d' % val
            self.val = val
    def strrep(self):
            print 'ConcretePlugin = %d' % self.val
            return
    #'idle' method implementation is missing
    def say(self): # missing argument here; saying our own word =)
            print 'ConcretePlugin: this is my word'
            return
```

This test:

```
child = ConcretePlugin(307)
child.strrep()
child.idle()
child.say()
```

produces the following result:

```
initialising ConcretePlugin with value of 307
ConcretePlugin = 307
PluginBase: doing nothing here
ConcretePlugin: this is my word
```

No whimpering about incomplete implementation!

So my question is whether Abstract Base Classes are not truly abstract. And if they aren't then is some way to make robust typing?

**Note:** I've named example classes `PluginBase` and `CompletePlugin` to show that I need to make sure that client classes implement the proper interface.

I've tried deriving `PluginBase` from `object`, but this makes no difference.
I'm using Python 2.7.1

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `__metaclass` to `__metaclass__`. Otherwise it's just a normal hidden attribute.

```
>>> ConcretePlugin(123)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class ConcretePlugin with abstract methods idle
```

Comment: Thanks! Turns out that I've asked another silly question! I'll mark answer as accepted when 7 minutes elapse and I'm allowed to do it :)